# Docker container won't run: "file already closed" error

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a docker image, but I keep getting an error that I'm unfamiliar with. I'm not sure if I'm explaining the issue in enough detail, so please let me know if any additional information is needed.

I run the docker image using this command: `sudo docker run -d --publish 5000:5000 -v backend-files:/Files anomaly-detection-api`

The docker image anomaly-detection-api is loaded correctly, and I've created a volume called backend-files.

[image]

This is the output from that command:

[image]

Please help!!

Comment: Do you work with huge amount of open files?

Comment: No I don't this so

Comment: The two PNG files you show are stored in that named volume?  What is the text output of the commands?  Beyond the `docker run` command, can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

friend. I just solved a difficult problem, and usually what I do is rapidly close a dozen tabs, but I figure today I will write something out first, that has a chance of helping some other poor sap with the same problem as me. Maybe this won't work for you, dear reader.

But for me -- I am running Fedora 32, x86_64 Linux 5.11.12-100.fc32.x86_64 -- what it turned out I'd done is start Docker in a stupid way. I'd done

```
sudo docker &
```

in a different terminal to run it as a background process, and was malding hard when everything kept popping up errors. Eventually I figured out I was supposed to use systemctl, but the bad Docker vibes had been released. So what I had to do -- this is ripped off of some other thread (perhaps from [here](https://gist.github.com/mattlockyer/baf87b34a683187303b3a866b355da30)) -- was destroy all running Dockers with this.

```
sudo ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh
```

and then

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

This ended up making things run properly -- for now, at least.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!! That was a difficult one as error messages are very misleading from the start. It all started with `Failed to start docker.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files`